# Fetch POST and DELETE methods with Rails are not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm using Rails API backend with a vanilla JS, HTML, and CSS frontend. I'm trying to add an upvote system, like Reddit for different food recipes in this app. Right now, I'm having 2 issues: my PATCH and DELETE methods within each fetch request are not working.

For both methods, I get a 404 (Not Found). This is my first time working with Rails as an API and JS, so I'm definitely a novice at this.

JS file:

```
function votingEvents(voting) {
  for (let i = 0; i < voting.length; i++) {
    voting[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
      if (event.target.style.color === '') {
        fetch(RECIPES_URL, {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            upvotes: `${this.upvotes + 1}`,
          })
        })
        .then( res => res.json())
        .then( res => event.target.dataset.upvotes = res.upvotes)
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
        event.target.style.color = "red"
        this.upvotes += 1
      } else if (event.target.style.color === 'red'){
          debugger
          event.target.style.color = ''
          fetch(RECIPES_URL, {
            method: "DELETE"
          })
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Rails Recipe Controller:

```
def update 
    recipe = Recipe.find_by(id: params[:id])
    recipe.upvotes += 1;
    render json: recipe
end

def destroy
    recipes = Recipe.all
    recipe = Recipe.find(id: params[:id])
    recipe.upvotes -= 1;
    render json: recipes
end
```

Comment: both methods require id parameters, don't see an id being passed anywhere

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Should I include an id parameter in the body of the fetch? For example in the PATCH method, under: upvotes: `${this.upvotes + 1}`,

Comment: it's part of the URL (route), which is why you are getting the not found errors

Comment: Okay, awesome. I've updated my URL route:
 fetch(RECIPES_URL + "/" + event.target.value, {


 However, not sure how I can find the id for (in this case), a specific recipe. Any ideas? For now, I filled in event.target.value, but it's returning 404

Comment: How are you showing the recipe if you don't know what it is?

Comment: So, I'm fetching the recipes from backend, rendering them, and placing an upvote icon next to the listed number of upvotes, like this: <span class="upvotes"><b>${this.upvotes} Upvotes <i class="fas fa-fire-alt" style="font-size:24px"></i></b></span>                                     So, after they're rendered, I'm adding an event listener to all class items labeled "fas fa-fire-alt", to add an upvote. When a click action happens, this event listener is triggered, but it doesn't seem to have a connection to the recipe that has been rendered.